# use function to the items in list

Tags: python, list, attributeerror

originally, beaker is instance and the function below is possible.
`beaker.replace(z=10)`

I made a list of beakers
`bk = [beaker1, beaker2, beaker3]` 
and I want all beaker to give function 'replace' like
`beaker1.replace(z=10)  beaker2.replace(z=10) beaker3.replace(z=10)`

so I made it brief but it does not work

```
bk = [beaker1, beaker2, beaker3]
for item in bk :
    item.replace(z=10)
```

but it says

```
    item.replace(z=10)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are posting the exact code? Seems like a typo somewhere

Comment: I corrected it. do u know how to fix it?

Comment: That's not the problem, for line might be different, `item` is not the  right temporary variable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing out `item` that you are looping to be sure? It said that `item` is a list like:

```py
bk = [beaker1, beaker2, beaker3]
for item in bk :
    print(item)
    print(type(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

As it said, `list` has no attribute `replace`, but `string` has

```py
bk = [beaker1, beaker2, beaker3]
bk = [10 if i == beaker1 else i for i in bk]
```

You don't have to write `z = 10` as in Java or other languages. Only when you do want to bind `10` to `z`.  Instead you can do it like this.

Comment: As the code, you can replace "replace" with "if" and "for" in a new list like I showed

Comment: replace(z=10) is a function I made for my own purpose. And basically if I do beaker.replace(z=10) solely, it works.    And my purpose is to adapt 'replace' function to all beaker(1,2,3,.............100....) automatically.

Comment: Ohhh I see. But I am not sure that the method in Python can rewrite as this. I highly recommend you to use a function but not a method. Just define a new function and return the updated beaker perhaps works